# 3 Way Switch is tripping breaker

Tags: electrical

I just re-wired a single pole light switch to a 3 way (using 14-3 wires) - [following the diagram as laid out here](https://www.hometips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/3-way-switch-wiring-diagram-1.png) but when I have the lone switch in the down position and move the one that is being fed from the box it immediately trips the breaker. I have triple checked all wires match the aforementioned diagram. Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

Comment: yes, the switches are not connected correctly

Comment: that drawing is wrong

Comment: Please upload pictures showing all the wires going to each switch.

Comment: If wired per the diagram it would work correctly, so you need to overcome the belief that it's wired as per the diagram, and figure out where you made a mistake. Then again, the diagram is inapplicable to new (or remodel) work in an area subject to NEC 2011 or later, where you'll need a neutral at each switch box, so the cable with the hot white as shown would need to be 14/4.

Comment: The diagram is also atypical in that in many houses, the power comes to the light first, not the switch first, and that could lead you astray if blindly following a "power to switch first" diagram...

Comment: I was under the impression that neutral had to be available at one of the two switches, not both

Comment: Ok. So what is the preferred layout for up to date code?  I see the layout I posted in multiple places. Also I can only get one wire to the one light switch due to the way the walls and fire stops are….

Comment: https://cdnassets.hw.net/dims4/GG/1ed7e3a/2147483647/resize/480x%3E/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdnassets.hw.net%2Fc5%2Fd6%2Fb7cf23a4421f90ee5944799e3584%2Fjlc-fg-electrical-three-way-switches-with-the-fixture-in-between.jpg I assume would be better?  So realistically it’s the same diagram just with a 14-4 wire to the one box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If forced to guess I'd say you have one of the travellers and the neutral confused.

Comment: Yup. Newly wired switch tripping the breaker pretty much always means the switch is wired to short the supply. Triple-checking only works if you triple-check correctly - if you did it wrong once for some reason and triple-check it to be the way you did it wrong three times, it's still wrong.

Comment: It turns out I had the switch wires labeled wrong. Once I swapped that backwards error they started working